# Symfony2 datetime queryBuilder

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I have 2 [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) classes in Symfony2 project. I have entity **Stat**, in which have **$date** property.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", length="11")
 */
protected $date;
```

I have to make queries using **DateTime** objects in **createQueryBuilder**. How can i do that ? For example:

```
$date_from = new DateTime('2012-02-01');
$date_to = new DateTime('2012-02-15');
```

I need to get all rows from table **stats** (entity **Stat**) between $date_from and $date_to. How should i write my query with createQueryBuilder ? My current code is:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select('s')
            ->from('ACME\MyBundle\Entity\Stat', 's')
            ->where('s.date >= :date_from')
            ->andWhere('s.date <= :date_to')
            ->setParameter('date_from', $date_from)
            ->setParameter('date_to', $date_to)
            ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Does your code not work?

Comment: it works... i found problem elsewhere

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Benjamin's answer is correct, but it lacks one detail.
This is the correct way to do it:

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->between('s.date', ':date_from', ':date_to'));
```

But to set parameters, I need to do like this:

```
$qb->setParameter('date_from', $date_from, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME);
$qb->setParameter('date_to', $date_to, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME);
```

If I omit the DATETIME types, I get the following error (see [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-697)):

> Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

I am using Doctrine DBAL 2.0.5, this behaviour might have changed in later versions of Doctrine.

Comment: _Note:_ Off site link is broken

Answer (score 10):

A QueryBuilder is a good solution.

But you can use

```
->andWhere($qb->expr()->between('s.date', ':date_from', ':date_to'))
```

or

```
->andWhere($qb->expr()->andX(array(
    $qb->expr()->gte('s.date', ':date_from'),
    $qb->expr()->lte('s.date', ':date_to'))
)
```

The $qb->expr()->andX is usefull if you don't want to have some WTF when you add some andWhere or orWhere.

[Here you have doctrine2 documentation for queryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html)

You can also use setParameters method for your parameters

```
->setParameters(array(
    'date_from' => $date_from,
    'date_to'   => $date_to,
))
```

Comment: I ran into an issue where both date_from and date_to are the same day, in that case no results where returned. The problem was that I was using DateTime, so it was looking for results on that very second (mightnight) for that day.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation. I couldn't use ->setParameter because of how my code was built, so i put this $andX variable to "catch" all the conditions founded in the foreach loop (in this case i just wrote the one with the dates because other are not relevant right now).

```
    $this->qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $andX = $this->qb->expr()->andX();
    $this->qb->select('u')
    ->from('models\User','u');          

        foreach($data as $key=>&$value){

            if($key == 'date'){

               $from = $this->qb->expr()->gte('u.date_from',$this->qb->expr()->literal($value['datefrom']));
               $to = $this->qb->expr()->lte('u.date_to',$this->qb->expr()->literal($value['dateto']));
               $condition = $from. ' AND ' .$to;

               $andX->add($condition);
             }

      //other if

         }
```

Notice that the parameter for this function is a multidimensional array. Hope this is helpful.