# Symfony2 Datetime field equal/bigger than

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I've read that [Symfony2 datetime queryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493992/symfony2-datetime-querybuilder)

My controller:

```
public function cgetSearchAction($date_from,$date_to)
{
    $dateFrom = new \DateTime();
    $dateFrom->setTimestamp($date_from);

    $dateTo = new \DateTime();
    $dateTo->setTimestamp($date_to);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository("MyBundle:Task")->getTasksFromTo($dateFrom,$dateTo);

    return array(
       'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
```

my Repo:

```
public function getTasksFromTo($date_from,$date_to)
{
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $tasks = $qb
            ->select('t')
            ->from('My\Bundle\Entity\Task', 't')
            ->where($qb->expr()->between('t.timeStart', ':date_from', ':date_to'))
            ->setParameter('date_from', $date_from, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
            ->setParameter('date_to', $date_to, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        return $tasks;

}
```

When I run in my database this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Task`  
WHERE `time_start` >= '01-04-2014'
AND `time_start` <= '07-04-2014'
```

I'm getting one row. If in symfony I change second date to 08-04-2014 - then also I'm getting this row.

So the second date MUST be BIGGER then date in a row that I want to get, it can't be equal. How can I change that so I could get rows which dates are equal/bigger than given?

Comment: Can't tell for certain, but it feels like you date format is off. You should use `ISO` format only: YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: well, as You can see I'm not formatting my date anywhere.